# Invoke an alexa skill from an alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a skill now that plays a stream. Once the stream is initialized, you can't interact with the skill anymore except for a few built in commands. I want to ask alexa what is playing. I have an API with all of this information. My idea was to spin up another skill that would get the deviceId, do some magic matching, spit out the response and then issue a call to launch the stream skill again. The problem is that I can find no documentation about calling a skill with code. I imagine that this should be possible if I issue a JSON to the skill endpoint. Does anyone have any advice or experience on this?

Answer (score -1):

This is currently not possible. But you can add an intent to your current skill that responds to 'Alexa ask SKILL_NAME what is playing'. In the IntentHandler you can have the code run that would get the data.